# Abrir página em forma de modal

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, modal, crud

estou fazendo um crud e gostaria de abrir uma outra página em forma de modal, mas não sei como fazer isso, até encontrei em um site explicando como fazer com javascript mas ao clicar no botão nada acontece.
Alguém conseguiria me ajudar? Na página Index queria abrir a página Create em forma de modal.

Página Index:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-dark">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8"><h3>Index</h3></div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <button type="button"
                    onclick="criar()"/>
            @Html.ActionLink("+", "Create")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@{

    <script>
        function criar() {
            $("#modalCreate").load("/Pracas/Create", function () {
                $("#modalCreate").show();
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Página Create:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Create</h4>

        texto
    </div>
}
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Coloque também o seu código JavaScript pra ficar mais claro o que você está tentando fazer

Comment: Maycon, eu adicionei o javascript que estava faltando!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz em uma pagina, eu também tive a mesma duvida mas! a resposta e bem simples.

No evento do botão e só por o seguinte código,

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "_new", "window.open('paginaCreate .aspx?modo=consultar','','toolbar=no,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,fullscreen=yes');", true);
```

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela resposta Wallafe!

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar um @Html.Partial("nome_modal") para carregar o seu código html na página index. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

Página Index:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

  @Html.Partial("_Create") @*coloque o nome da sua página modal aqui*@

<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-dark">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8"><h3>Index</h3></div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <button type="button"
                    onclick="criar()"/>
            @Html.ActionLink("+", "Create")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@{

    <script>
        function criar() {
            $("#modalCreate").load("/Pracas/Create", function () {
                $("#modalCreate").show();
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Página Create:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Create</h4>

        texto
    </div>
}
```